# Android - How to import an Eclipse project made in windows to Mac

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android project which has made in Eclipse on Windows, now I need to import that project into Eclipse on Mac.

I'm trying to use the Import Projects tool. The problem is the project is not showed in the Projects list to be selected.

Is there another way to import the project into an Eclipse Mac? Or maybe I need to do something different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can export that project as archive file then load it into mac

Comment: Eclipse shouldn't care if the project was created on Windows or Mac. How did you export the project?

Comment: I use Mac and Windows interchangeably, with the project shared through git. The only issue I have is that CR/LF sometimes get mangled in layout files. Everything else just works -- even CDT/NDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find what was my problem.

I had all of my projects inside a workspace folder. So, every time I tried to import my projects into my new Mac Eclipse, I could not see them in the projects list.

The thing was I take out my projects from that workspace folder and Eureka, Eclipse could list the projects and I could import them.

I hope it helps someone.