# Switching Windows to MacOS - Problem importing the workspace from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Well, I just bought a secondhand Macbook and I want to import my workspace from Windows.

I tried deleting the folder .metadata and still not working.
I also tried to copy the folders with the projects in the workspace and then go to general>import existing projects... and anything appears in the menu and I cant finish the process.

I don't know what steps I have to follow now. Also I got a message that advice me that this workspace was programmed in other version of eclipse.

I tried to type in the terminal:

defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

but Eclipse dont found the .project to open my workspace.

Thx if you have read everything.

SOLUTION: I save the workspace in Google Drive and when you download the folder, google drive zipped and change the .project into _project for no reason. What I do was to create the Google Drive sync folder and by this way, it maintains the .project with no changes.

Comment: Hello Jose try to delete those files to: .project, .settings, .classpath than open that project in your mac.

Comment: I deleted the .metadata but I cant find the files you say.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an Eclipse project from Windows to Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964572/how-to-import-an-eclipse-project-from-windows-to-mac-os)

Comment: Or of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390170/android-how-to-import-an-eclipse-project-made-in-windows-to-mac

Comment: Or of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471541/importing-eclipse-workspace-from-windows-to-mac-os-x-mavericks

Comment: Bottom line: please make sure to [search SO, and the web, before posting a question](/help/how-to-ask) because it's almost guaranteed someone already had this problem in the past. If you're new to SO, _definitely_ give that policy article a one-time thorough read (ideally _before_ posting your first question, but you already did), because we're all expected to follow the "rules" set out in it. Further userful articles to have read at least once are the [what is on-topic for SO](/help/on-topic) and [SO's code of conduct](/conduct) policy articles.

Comment: It doesn't works for me so I decided to post.

Comment: @JoseManuelMartínezSoler those files is hidden use that combination to show hidden files cmd + shift + .  than you can see the files.

Comment: Check out from version control again.